# Java Runtime Exception when launching activity from fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-fragments

My app force quits when I attempt to launch an activity from within a fragment as soon as the user taps on the button (the button is in the fragment, and is supposed to launch the activity).

I get the following errors when trying to launch an activity from within a fragment (relevant logcat output shown):

```
...
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to         instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.vutoch.myapp/com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.TextViewActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.TextViewActivity.<init>(TextViewActivity.java:27)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
03-13 18:07:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):    ... 11 more
```

From within my TextViewFragment, I am attempting to launch the TextViewActivity. That gives the above error.

TextViewFragment:

```
package com.vutoch.myapp.Fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.vutoch.myapp.R;
import com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.SettingsActivity;
import com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.TextViewActivity;
import com.vutoch.myapp.Utils.DownloadFile;
import com.vutoch.myapp.Utils.GeneralUtils;

public class TextViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private static View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

            // Download the file and return its path.
            String newFilePath = new DownloadFile().createDownloadFile();
            Log.v("FRAG_FILEPATH", "Path = " + newFilePath);

            // If the button is clicked, the app force quits!
            final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),     TextViewActivity.class);
                    //Intent newIntent = new Intent(TextViewFa, TextViewActivity.class);

                    startActivity(newIntent);
                }
            });


            //Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), TextViewActivity.class);
            //startActivity(newIntent);
        }


        catch (InflateException e) {
            final String errorMsg = "The text view could not be loaded.";
            GeneralUtils.showDialogBox(view.getContext(), "Text View Fragment Error", errorMsg);
            Log.v("TextView_Inflate_Fail", errorMsg);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

The activity that TextviewFragment attempts to launch is as below:

TextViewActivity:

```
package com.vutoch.myapp.Activities;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vutoch.myapp.R;
import com.vutoch.myapp.Database.DbHelper;
import com.vutoch.myapp.Database.DbQuery;

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public class TextViewActivity extends Activity {
     ListView listView;
     final String DB_FULL_PATH = "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_textview);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        DbHelper dbh = new DbHelper(this);
        try {
            dbh.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Create database failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();

        // Get all entries from the MTOresults table.
        // We use this as a sample for now.
        String[] whereArgs = { "1" };
        Cursor values = DbQuery.runSqlQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM MTOresults where Iid >= ?", whereArgs);

        /* Start list adapter code -- DO NOT REMOVE */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
             android.R.id.text1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Show Alert 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position:" +itemPosition 
                    +"  ListItem: " + itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          });
        /* End list adapter code */
        setupActionBar();
     }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

For reference, here is my Android manifest file:

```
AndroidManifest.XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.vutoch.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="2.0-build20140209-tony" >

<permission
    android:name="com.vutoch.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.vutoch.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Use openGL -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCd2BdcE8rInSxBZ9QXdPdYviOIvTtMpUo" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.TextViewActivity"
        android:label="Text View" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.vutoch.myapp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I hope that is all the necessary information (I'm new to Android). I think that the line which is causing the problem is the one that launches the explicit intent (in TextViewFragment):

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TextViewActivity.class);
```

Any idea as to why its not working? Cannot figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: That's really too much code. Take some time to whittle it down, and you'll get more assistance. As it stands, it's too much to work through.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `view.getContext()` use `TextViewFragment.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()`.